# How to check if member has a role discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I've tried `message.member.roles.cache.has(id)`, and `message.member.roles.has(id)`, but they both don't work.

Comment: We need more context, can you show surrounding code aswell as how you defined `id`

Comment: Possible resource you could use: https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/understanding/roles.md

Comment: Could you provide more details like the error or more of the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

A common fix is to first fetch the GuildMember to put it into the cache.

You can use the following to do that, but make sure to make your function [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await):

```js
await message.member.fetch()
```

After that you should be able to use the code you provided (`message.member.roles.cache.has(id)`).